# SVG: Define <defs> once on page, use in multiple <svg>?

Tags: html, svg

I want to be able to define a mask once with `<defs>` on a page then reuse it within multiple `<svg>` elements.

For example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
  <clipPath id="SvgjsClipPath1009">
    <rect width="200%" height="80%" x="0" y="20%"></rect>
    <rect width="200%" height="80%" x="0" y="20%"></rect>
  </clipPath>
</defs>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g clip-path="url(#SvgjsClipPath1009)">
<image class="Chevron-Image" xlink:href="http://placekitten.com/g/1200/1200" width="1200" height="1200" x="50%" y="50%"></image>
</g>
</svg>
```

Currently this does not work in Chrome. Is there a trick to doing this or do all SVGs have to be self-contained?

Comment: One trap to look out for: if your defs-only svg is a child of a element that has "display:none" as a style, it will not be part of the page.

Comment: @natetitterton, your comment helped me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Cross-fragment references seem to work just fine in Chrome. But since you haven't specified explicit sizes for the svg fragments they behave differently in Firefox and Chrome.

If we take your example and specify the sizes then it works the same in both.

E.g add `svg { width: 200px; height: 200px }` in a stylesheet. Here's that [as a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2HZ7f/).

Answer (score 1):

You can inline the SVG with the `<defs>` and inline the SVG with the references/styles.

```
<html>
<body>
    <style>svg rect{fill:url(#bg);}</style>
    <svg><defs><linearGradient id="bg"></defs></svg>
    <svg><rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" /></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

(HTML and SVG trimmed for brevity)